# How to parse SOAP response with PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

Below is the SOAP response of flight ticket booking  i got. How to parse this response in PHP.I need to get the values inside the tags.For example the value 12 inside the tag 'KLRCnt'.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <SubmitXmlOnSessionResponse
            xmlns="http://webservices.galileo.com">
            <SubmitXmlOnSessionResult>
                <PNRBFManagement_21
                    xmlns="">
                    <PNRBFRetrieve>
                        <Control>
                            <KLRCnt>12</KLRCnt>
                        </Control>
                   <PNRBFRetrieve>    
                </PNRBFManagement_21>
            </SubmitXmlOnSessionResult>
        </SubmitXmlOnSessionResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`
```

Comment: I got two solutions for this                                                                 1.Clean all soap tags                                                                       $clean_xml = str_ireplace(['<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">', '<soapenv:Body>', '</soapenv:Body>', '</soapenv:Envelope>'], '', $string);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml);

Comment: 2.Use dom document                                                                                    $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML($string);
        echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('KLRCnt')->item(0)->nodeValue;

Comment: this has been answered on SO many times, please search.